# Do melee damage weapon mods affect heavy melee?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I just received my first +melee damage weapon mod in multiplayer (a Blade Attachment for my Geth Plasma Shotgun, woohoo!). Does the increased melee damage also count for my heavy melee attack, or is it only for my regular melee attacks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on my *Single player* testing, yes it does increase your heavy melee damage.

Tested this by doing the following:

Vanguard with all relevant powers maxed

> Character with maxed fitness (including all of the possible melee damage buffs) and a stunner on my pistol (no melee damage armor). Facing a marauder (with full health and shields), I could kill him in one biotic charge followed by a heavy melee.

Followed by a vanguard with 0 melee focus

> Character with 0 fitness, and no stunner or melee armor (meaning default melee damage). Facing a marauder (with full health and shields), I required at least 1 followup light melee swing after a biotic charge/heavy melee combo.

Testing specifically weapon mods, I got the following results:

> Vanguard with minor melee buffs (the default ones, choosing all health/shields choices where possible) against Cerberus Centurions.
>
> While wielding a shotgun without the blade attachment, one heavy melee would leave the centurion with 2 bars of shields left (from full health/shields)
>
> While wielding a pistol with a +22.50% melee damage stunner, one heavy melee would leave the centurion with no shields and between full health and one bar of health damage.

This shows that weapon mods do improve heavy melee.

> Note all tests were done in singleplayer, but I'm assuming multiplayer results will be the same.

Comment: I'm aware that the passive upgrades will increase it, however, I was *specifically* wondering about weapons mods and their effect. I'll edit my question to make that clearer. I'd be interested to see your results with a character who has the same stats with only the weapon mod as a variable.

Comment: @FAE Brb, retesting.

Comment: @FAE Did some testing and updated my answer.